# Unable to trace when order status for an order is marked complete in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, php, ce-1.9.0.1

For an order, when an invoice is created the order status changes to processing. Now, if a shipment is created the order status changes to Complete.

On debugging the code.. I have been able to find out the place where shipment save occurs.

Below is the file path:
app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Sales\Order\ShipmentController.php

In the following function:

```
 protected function _saveShipment($shipment)
    {
        $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
        $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
            ->addObject($shipment)
            ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
            ->save();
         return $this;
    }
```

I tried debugging the shipment variable data, but the status values show up as processing. But after the _saveShipment function is executed the order status changes to Complete

Could anyone tell me at what point the order status changes to Complete.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: Hello, The status of the Order changes when there is Shipment and Invoice. Even if you create a Shipment and then create an Invoice status will be changed to Complete. Because the Code for the Status is not available under the Shipment or Invoice classes but under the Magento Order classes.

Answer (score 0):

I found the code in

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order
```

Look for statement

```
$this->_setState(self::STATE_COMPLETE, true, '', $userNotification);
```

in below function

```
protected function _checkState()
    {
        if (!$this->getId()) {
            return $this;
        }

        $userNotification = $this->hasCustomerNoteNotify() ? $this->getCustomerNoteNotify() : null;

        if (!$this->isCanceled()
            && !$this->canUnhold()
            && !$this->canInvoice()
            && !$this->canShip()) {
            if (0 == $this->getBaseGrandTotal() || $this->canCreditmemo()) {
                if ($this->getState() !== self::STATE_COMPLETE) {
                    $this->_setState(self::STATE_COMPLETE, true, '', $userNotification);
                }
            }
            /**
             * Order can be closed just in case when we have refunded amount.
             * In case of "0" grand total order checking ForcedCanCreditmemo flag
             */
            elseif (floatval($this->getTotalRefunded()) || (!$this->getTotalRefunded()
                && $this->hasForcedCanCreditmemo())
            ) {
                if ($this->getState() !== self::STATE_CLOSED) {
                    $this->_setState(self::STATE_CLOSED, true, '', $userNotification);
                }
            }
        }

        if ($this->getState() == self::STATE_NEW && $this->getIsInProcess()) {
            $this->setState(self::STATE_PROCESSING, true, '', $userNotification);
        }
        return $this;
    }
```